# Probability that order statistic is larger than the other

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

> Given the density function:
>
> $$f_Y(y)=e^{-(y+1)}, y>-1$$
>
> Let $Y_1,..,Y_4$ be a random sample from the distribution defined by the density function above. Let $Y_{(1)},..,Y_{(4)}$ be the order statistics of $Y_1,..,Y_4$.
>
> Find $P(Y_{(1)}<3Y_{(2)})$

**Edit 3:** Seems I have it right with finding the joint distribution for this. However, according to the formula:

$$f_{Y(i),Y(j)}(y_i,y_j)=\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(j-i-1)!(n-j)!}*F(y_i)^{i-1}*[F(y_j)-F(y_i)]^{j-i-1}*[1-F(y_j)]^{n-j}*f(y_i)*f(y_j)$$

I get:

$$f_{Y(1),Y(2)}(y_1,y_2)=12*e^{-3(y_2+1)}*e^{-(y_1+1)}, y_1,y_2>-1$$

Which is not a probability function. What am I doing wrong?

Furthermore, I think I should do the completing probability as it is easier, and simply have 1-* to reach the probability I seek. Do I have the double integral right at least:

$$\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^\frac{Y_1}{3}f_{Y(1),Y(2)}(y_1,y_2)dy_2dy_1$$

I believe so and the result I get is probably off because of having some mistake with the joint distribution function, which I simply can not spot.

Comment: Sometimes they use order statistics in reverse order. So $Y_{(1)}$ might represent highest, $Y_{(2)}$ represent second highest and so on.

Comment: Not under my definition.

Comment: Since variables may come from second quandrant than it is possible to have $Y_{(1)}\geq 3 Y_{(2)}$ Consider the following random variables $Y_1=-1/3$, $Y_2=-1/2$ $Y_3=1$ and $Y_4=0$

Comment: Hah, I see, then I should compute the distribution of each and then.. what should I do? Compare the two? How do I get to a probability from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint distribution of $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(2)})$ is actually
$$f_{Y_{(1)},Y_{(2)}}(y_1,y_2)=12\,\mathrm e^{-3(y_2+1)}\,\mathrm e^{-(y_1+1)}\,\mathbf 1_{y_2\gt y_1>-1},
$$
hence
$$
P(Y_{(1)}\lt3Y_{(2)})=\iint f_{Y_{(1)},Y_{(2)}}(y_1,y_2)\,\mathbf 1_{y_1\lt3y_2}\,\mathrm dy_1\mathrm dy_2.
$$
It happens that somewhat simpler computations are involved if one considers
$$
P(Y_{(1)}\gt3Y_{(2)})=\iint f_{Y_{(1)},Y_{(2)}}(y_1,y_2)\,\mathbf 1_{y_1\gt3y_2}\,\mathrm dy_1\mathrm dy_2,
$$
since $y_1\gt3y_2$ and $y_2\gt y_1>-1$ imply $y_1\lt0$ hence
$$
P(Y_{(1)}\gt3Y_{(2)})=\int_{-1}^0\int_{y_1}^{y_1/3}12\,\mathrm e^{-3(y_2+1)}\,\mathrm e^{-(y_1+1)}\,\mathrm dy_2\mathrm dy_1=\int_0^14\mathrm e^{-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{(x_1+2)/3}3\mathrm e^{-3x_2}\,\mathrm dx_2\mathrm dx_1,
$$
and maybe you can finish?

Comment: My saviour! I had doubts as I did the double integral on the whole bound it didn't reach 1, apperently my faulty was elsewhere. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Out of curiousity, any intutive commment about why (against my intution at least) the probability that $Y_{(1)}<3Y_{(2)}$ is actually smaller than the completence? I would think otherwise as $Y_{(1)}<Y_{(2)}$ by definition.

Comment: @Studentmath This is a bit late, but it's because the values can be negative, and multiplying a negative by 3 results in a lesser number.  Consider the case: $Y_{(1)} = -\frac 1 2, Y_{(2)} =-\frac 1 4 \implies Y_{(1)} > 3Y_{(2)}$

Answer (score 0):

This is mechanized in Maple. Note that Maple uses [the standard definition of the order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).
$$restart; with(Statistics):
X := RandomVariable(Distribution(PDF = (y ->piecewise(-1 < y, exp(-y-1), 0) ))):
Y1 := OrderStatistic(X, 1, 4): PDF(Y1, t);
  $$ The latter command outputs
$$\cases{0&$t\leq -1$\cr 4\,{{\rm e}^{-4-4\,t}}&$-1<t$\cr}$$ 
Next $$Y2 := OrderStatistic(X, 2, 4): PDF(Y2, t); $$ produces $$ \cases{0&$t\leq -1$\cr 12\,{{\rm e}^{-2-2\,t}} \left( {{\rm e}^{-1-t}}-1 \right) ^{2}&$-1<t$\cr}$$ At last, $$Probability(Y1 < 3*Y2); $$ gives 
$$-9/4\,{{\rm e}^{-8/3}}+{\frac {16\,{{\rm e}^{-2}}}{5}}=0.2767351410.
 $$ See [Distribution](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics%2fDistribution) and [OrderStatistic](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics%2fOrderStatistic) for info.